# show a constant admob ad banner in all activities

Tags: android, admob, banner

i want to show a constant banner in all activities without multiple ad request.
like that in main activity ad mob banner will overlay in all other activities.

here is the link that i want to like this app

Click [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.northpark.drinkwater)

thanks

Comment: You should take one activity and then define banner on that activity and take fragments to show different screens.

Comment: thanks for replaying Andrain.i tried out this but problem is that if i go to another activity then it will call ad request on fragment or how i overlay fragment in all activities?

Comment: is there any way to stop calling oncreateactivity() method on all activities after banner is loaded?

Comment: No u can not avoid onCreate() method on activity.

Answer (score 0):

What Adrian has said is the best solution to your problem.

Create a MainActivity with multiple Fragments. One Fragment contains your AdView and is will always be visible. The other Fragments contain the user interface that you are currently providing in other Activities. These other Fragments are made visible or not visible (or added/removed) as the user navigates between these screens.

Comment: Adrian's solution does work but there has to be something better. Orchestrating you app design so Admob will work better smells like a bad solution to me.

Comment: It is using the tools you have in the way they were designed to be used.